# What's actually wrong here? Should we always avoid even mentioning or citing the present within a question post?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've asked the following [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/72504/33008) (shown below) and two down votes and two close votes immediately appeared. So I (at least temporarily) deleted it and decide to explore the issue further here first.

One comment said:

> This is not a historical question. The events you mention are current. Try a legal stack.

to which I replied

> That's a mischaracterization, I've asked for "Historical instances of..." The current events are cited only to help illustrate the motivation of my question and the type of thing I'm asking about. It helps inform answer authors of why I'm asking - I'm trying to get here better historical context with which to view current events. The better that answer authors understand what it is I'm trying to understand, the better they can address it in answers.

My feeling is that the mere mention of a current event within my post triggered the quick responses and that an actual read-through of the question, or even the title itself would have been enough to dispel the concern.

I'm literally asking for history here, but I'm explaining why I'm asking. *Is that the problem?*  Should we always avoid even mentioning or citing the present within a question post?

---

> **title:** Historical instances of campaigns for elected law enforcement positions where candidate runs on "out to get person X" as major part of their message?
>
> The motivation of my question is to explore the history of elected US officials who run "out to get X" campaigns. What got me interested is the following quote from CNN's October 3, 2023 [Judge rebuts attacks from Trump's attorney in $250M civil case](https://youtu.be/hkcvk8K0-4g?t=47)
>  where the (quite famous) former US president states to the press outside the courtroom:
>
> > We have a racist Attorney General who's a horror show, **who ran on the basis that she was going to get Trump** before she even know anything about me.
>
> For any literate person not to "know anything about" the defendant here is more than unlikely, but the idea of running a campaign based on "going to get" someone is interesting.
>
> Have there been **other, historical instances of campaigns** for elected law enforcement positions where a candidate has run on "out to get person X" as a major part of their message?
>
> Are such campaigns extremely few and been widely seen has personal vendettas, or have they perhaps been an accepted platform from time to time as certain public figures become recognized as "untouchable criminals" in need of being "gotten"?

Comment: I ask in many different SE sites (including Law and Politics) and it is always a challenge for me to switch back and forth keep track of how the expectations (and trigger-points) of each community differ (cf. [How is History SE not like Skeptics SE?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4164/33008)) I'm looking forward to constructive and *actionable* advice on how to ask this History SE question. *Thanks!*

Comment: One problem I see is that this would be a list type question. It is open ended, asking for instance*s*. These are often closed here. We prefer a question which can be answered with a single, correct and verifiable (through historical means) answer.  I would have voted to close it as too broad.

Comment: @justCal Thanks, that's exactly the kind of help I need. Perhaps an "Is there precedent for campaigning on 'get X'..." question might survive in Politics SE [if I "pray"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392500/303080), but I see now that anything along these lines won't fly here. For this meta question - In addition to the comment about "current events" I see that the two close votes were for "opinion-based" https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mBJ8.png so I think that can still be addressed in answers here.

Comment: As a tactical matter, yes its a good idea to avoid putting a lot of content in your question that looks off-topic, or to frontload such content in your question text. In the future if you have a lot of current-day background exposition you really want to add, I'd suggest putting your question as the first sentence so its clear what you're asking before people start reading sentence after sentence that look off topic and assume that's where you're going.

Comment: @T.E.D. there is of course the title which could be considered the first sentence  Mine was (as indicated above) "Historical instances of campaigns for elected law enforcement positions where candidate runs on "out to get person X" as major part of their message?" I suppose I could paste it again as the first sentence of the body but I'm pretty sure someone would immediately delete it as redundant. Are there a few good examples of question posts where the question is both in the title and again as the first sentence in the body? I'd like to see how that's done without looking redundant. Thanks

Comment: @T.E.D. your message about (avoiding) frontloading, especially with current content is well taken.